# How to refer a view inside include layout in android

Tags: android

Hi i have coded the following to get the view from include layout. But i am getting null pointer exception. Where i am wrong?

My Java Code:

```
View actionbar = findViewById(R.id.actionbar);
                RelativeLayout actionRRl = (RelativeLayout)actionbar.findViewById(R.id.actionRR);
                actionRRl.setEnabled(false);
                actionRRl.setClickable(false);
```

In my Activity.xml,

```
   <include
            android:id="@+id/actionbar"
            layout="@layout/actionbar" />
```

Layout that is included, ie., actionbar.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/header"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:id="@+id/actionRR"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:padding="@dimen/logo_size"
            android:src="@drawable/logo" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Error Stack:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Giving id to your included layout like below:

```
<include android:id="@+id/actionbar"
```

overrides your parent id in your included layout.

In your case, changing your code to this should fix the problem:

```
View actionbar = findViewById(R.id.actionbar);
actionbar.setEnabled(false);
actionbar.setClickable(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you include the toolbar layout to your activity, their components belong to your activity as well, so you can instantiate them directly

```
RelativeLayout actionRRl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.actionRR);
actionRRl.setEnabled(false);
actionRRl.setClickable(false);
```

Comment: Tried your code: Its throwing error mate!
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.RelativeLayout.setEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference

Comment: Please be sure that you are making the call after the `setContentView()`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
RelativeLayout actionRRl = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.actionRR);
                actionbar.setEnabled(false);
                actionbar.setClickable(false);
```

You can also inflate the layout to get a view and do it like this,

```
View actionbar = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.actionbar, null, false);
 RelativeLayout actionRRl = (RelativeLayout)actionbar.findViewById(R.id.actionRR);
                actionRRl.setEnabled(false);
                actionRRl.setClickable(false);
```

Comment: hi @Yordan, so what is actionbar here?

Comment: you don't need the actionBar, its a reference to a layout resource not a view.